# .gitignore Doesn't Track my Files Even After Using "git rm -r --cached ." and "git add ."?

Tags: git

I've run "git rm -r --cached ." and "git add ." several times now trying to fix this, among other things. Nothing's worked yet.

I have this [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiGcD.png), I want the untracked files to be ignored. This is my [.gitignore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hoxi.png)

Even when removing all cached files and readding everything, the untracked files *still* get tracked by git. My .gitignore is in the root of my repo, like it should be, and I believe I named all files correctly. Running "git ls-files . --ignored --exclude-standard --others" returns nothing, both when the files are tracked and untracked.

What's my issue here? Thank you.

Comment: Make sure your `.gitignore` file is plain text (not rich-text) and is stored as UTF-8 and no byte-order-mark. Using UTF-16-LE and/or rich-text is a common mistake.

Comment: Yep, second case was it. It was stored as UTF-16-LE. FIxed now. Thanks!

Comment: @torek Wow, what a choosy file-reading algorithm! No byte-order mark even??? Sheesh.

Comment: @matt: A BOM might be accepted-and-skipped, but I've never risked it. Of course a BOM in a UTF-8 file is pointless too...

Answer (score 1):

torek's comment above worked. My .gitignore was stored as UTF-16-LE. Creating the .gitignore within VSCode caused the issue, and deleting that and creating it right on github fixed it.